# Selecting fields using variable PHP

Tags: php, sql

how can I select the field using variable. I want to select the field (Seriennummer) in the base column (Seriennummer, MacAdresse).

I need to select meta_key columns, and meta_value where the variable $result is equal to meta_key.

Thanks to everyone for help.

I always get an error

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in \wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\checkout\thankyou.php

```html
$result = wpuef_get_field('c2');
$value=$result->value;
echo $value,"<br>";
//Sql
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "paymentdb");
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT Seriennummer, MacAdresse FROM set_top_box WHERE Seriennummer ='".$result."'";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Seriennummer</th>";
                echo "<th>MacAdresse</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Seriennummer'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['MacAdresse'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
```

[database picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZvhB.png)

Comment: You need to add your code here.And if you want to select that particular row then use the `umeta_id` pass the correct ID number to your `SQL` with a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: thanks for calling. My code is now set in a sql query I set up what I would like to do but I think I did not set a good variable.
can you correct me?

Comment: Your duplicating your `$results` use another to assign your results from the DB. I don't know if this `wpuef_cid_c2` is unique to each user and also don't know how you're sending the data to the above code. If this `wpuef_cid_c2 isn't unique then you will have lot duplicates getting selected. And if you want test just use `$result = "wpuef_cid_c2"` no need to put it in `$_POST[wpuef_cid_c2']`.

Answer (score 0):

**this is the result**

```html
$result = wpuef_get_field('c2');
$value=$result->value;
echo $value,"<br>";
//Sql
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "paymentdb");
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT Seriennummer, MacAdresse FROM set_top_box WHERE Seriennummer ='".$value=$result->value."'";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>Seriennummer</th>";
                echo "<th>MacAdresse</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['Seriennummer'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['MacAdresse'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
```